# count the number of phrases in a string faster

Tags: python, string, substring, nltk, n-gram

I have the following code that counts the desired phrases from a string:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams
from nltk import word_tokenize
import pandas as pd

def count_words(convo,df_search):
    for i in range(0,len(df_search)):
        word = df_search['word'][i] #set the word
        a=tuple(word.split(' '))
        print word, len([i for i in ngrams(word_tokenize(convo),n=len(a)) if i==a]) 

convo="I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree. Actually, there are more than one man under the tall tree"

df_search=pd.DataFrame({'word':['man','tall tree','is under the']})

count_words(convo,df_search)
```

The problem with the code is that it is really slow, it "re" `ngrams` each time to look for a new phrase. And that part of the phrase is dynamic, so I don't know how long the length. Need help changing the code to speed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you just replace your `print` statement with

```
print word, convo.count(word)
```

Comment: @alvas are there any problems with Robert's answer? This looks simple enough, why do the `ngrams` or `everygrams`?

Comment: Sure, for example the string "stall treets" (whatever that be) would also be counted as "tall tree" with this simple approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't mind using `re`:

```
import re
input_string = "I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree. Actually, there are more than one man under the tall tree"
word = ['man','tall tree','is under the']
for i in word:
    print i + ': ' + str(sum(1 for _ in re.finditer(r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(i), input_string)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the bleeding edge version of NLTK, there's an `everygrams` implementation, https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py#L464

You can simply do a count afterwards:

```
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.util import everygrams
>>> sent = word_tokenize("I see a tall tree outside. A man is under the tall tree. Actually, there are more than one man under the tall tree")
>>> ng = tuple(['tall', 'tree'])
>>> list(everygrams(sent)).count(ng)
3
```

If not, you can always create your own everygrams function (just cut and paste from https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/util.py#L464) and then do a count =)